# How to use landing pages (bootstrap) in a Django project?

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Dajngo project and I want to include a landing page to use it for home page, I was trying to use it on my own and guiding me in tutorials but I could not get it to load the CSS style. I am new using this framework (bootstrap), could anyone help me identify my error to load the CSS style please?

**Files:**

*setting.py*

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'crm', #app's name
        'bootstrap3',
    )

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
             },
         },
    ]

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

*mysite\urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView#TemplateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from crm import views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('crm.urls')),
]
```

*crm\urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from crm import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('crm.urls')),
]
```

*crm\views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Create your views here.
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'crm/index.html', context=None)
```

*bootstrap\index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Freelancer - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

In my crm folder I have 2 folders, static and templates folders and inside of them CSS files and HTML files respectively. I want to use this template [Freelancer](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/). Any comment is of help, thanks.

Comment: Can you show us `head` of`index.html`? We need to see how you include you stylesheets

Comment: @pythad Sure, wait a second please

Comment: @pythad Now you can see it

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `index.html` and use `{% static %}` tag for including your static files:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Freelancer - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/freelancer.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Comment: I already tried and it still does not load the CSS style, it only loads the HTML

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py include

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)`

after your definition of STATC_URL so that Django knows to look in the .../static directory where your index.html and css are located. Make sure that your BASE_DIR is pointing to the correct directory that your static files are located in.

Also, in index.html, you should include `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of your index.py and also use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/xxx.css' %}">` for each instance of the boostrap core, theme and custom fonts (so all parts of code that you follow the format above).

A good online django tutorial that goes over static files more in depth can be found [here](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/create-home-page-with-tdd-staticfiles-templates-settings#initializr).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I changed what you asked and still does not load the CSS style and thanks for the link, I hope that can solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The Django docs have a good tutorial for writing your first app. [Here is the page that explains how to load the css](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial06/).

The tags that load your css have the wrong href. They should be loaded with the Django static tag. First make sure you have all the files in your static folder. The one specified in STATIC_ROOT, so create the folder `<YOUR_BASE_DIR>/static/css/` and copy both `bootstrap.min.css` and `freelancer.min.css` there. To load them just change your template to use the correct path.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'css/freelancer.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I already did that, in fact I followed that Django documentation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can download `bootstrap.css` and save in your static file like this :

in `setting.py :`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**folders** of your project :

```
mysite/
   mysite1/
        setting.py
   mysite2/
        views.py
        urls.py
   static/
        css/
            bootstrap.css

  #folders name is cutom for me beacuse i dont khow you project folders
```

at top of your template use :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

and then in  tag of your **template** :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}">
```

have a happy codeing...